# intercepting the call to __await__ on an asyncio Task in Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

What I'm trying to do is to get notified whenever:

- an asyncio Task is created
- anyone awaits on an asyncio Task

The first one is straightforward - use a task factory.
For the second one - there are two implementation approaches I could think of:

1) Wrap the task with a new Python object that behaves like a future (enough to fool other code), forward whatever methods necessary to the wrapped task

2) monkey patch **await** in the original task to notify me, and then forward it to the original __await.

I tried to go for option (2) first because it seems easier. However, I can't get it to work. Attempts to modify **await** (directly or via **setattr**) seem to have no effect whatsoever.

Questions:

- Any way to get (2) to work?
- How safe is the (1) approach?
- Is there a "clean" way to wrap a task in a future that I could use?

Here's some code showing what I tried doing.

```
import asyncio

def patch_task_factory(loop):
    prior = loop.get_task_factory()
    def factory(loop, coro):
        if prior is None:
            task = asyncio.Task(coro, loop=loop)
        else:
            task = prior(loop, coro)

        # here we know a task has been created
        # but to also get notified when someone waits for it, we need to patch __await__
        orig_await = task.__await__

        def intercepted_await(self):
            print("someone is awaiting this task")
            # should work because we're just returning the iterator from the real await
            return orig_await(self)
        task.__await__ = intercepted_await.__get__(task, asyncio.Task)

        return task
    loop.set_task_factory(factory)


async def test1():
    print("test1!")
    return 1

async def test2():
    print("test2!")
    return await asyncio.create_task(test1())


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    patch_task_factory(loop)
    res = asyncio.run(test2())
    print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    main()
```

Comment: Why do you need such non-standard notifications? What is the "x" in this [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: calculating a "happens-before" relation on certain events happening inside async tasks. Part of the building the graph involved in the calculation relies on these two events, though there are others. 
Clearly there can't be a perfect solution to the general case, but I still need to do it on a "best effort" basis

BTW I already made a lot of progress today. Managed to do the "wrap a task with a future" approach. Monitoring __await__ isn't good enough on its own, though, because it does not cover use of as_completed or gather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Task` is a built-in/extension method, imported from `_asyncio` (note the underscore). You'll note that `setattr(task.__class__.__getattribute__, ...)`, for example, complains that you cannot modify method-wrappers of built-in classes.

You might consider a proxy object in this case. Note the "trickery" around overriding `__await__`:

`proxy.py` is taken straight from `http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741-object-proxying/`.

```
$ cat task_factory.py
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
from typing import Any, Generator
from proxy import Proxy


class ProxyWithAwait(Proxy):
    def __await__(self) -> Generator[Any, None, Any]:
        _obj = object.__getattribute__(self, "_obj")
        aw = _obj.__await__()
        print("*** INTERCEPTING AWAIT: BEFORE")
        yield aw.send(None)
        print("*** INTERCEPTING AWAIT: AFTER")
        aw.close()


async def main() -> None:

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    old_task_factory = loop.get_task_factory()

    def my_task_factory(
        loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop,
        coro: Generator[Any, None, Any],
    ) -> asyncio.Future:
        if old_task_factory is None:
            t = asyncio.tasks.Task(coro, loop=loop)
        else:
            t = old_task_factory(loop, coro)

        return ProxyWithAwait(t)

    loop.set_task_factory(my_task_factory)

    async def my_task_func() -> None:
        print("my_task_func(): start")
        await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
        print("my_task_func(): end")

    t = loop.create_task(my_task_func())
    print("main: before await t")
    await t
    print("main: after await t")

    loop.set_task_factory(old_task_factory)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```